# How to sign xml element using RSA-SHA1 algorithm?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, cryptography, digital-signature

I need to sign (and verify eventually) one of the nodes of an XML document using RSA-SHA1 algorithm. [w3.org link](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlsec-algorithms/)

> RSA-SHA1
>      URI:
>          http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
>      Specified in:
>          section 6.4.2 of [XMLDSIG-CORE2002]

I am following [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx),  however cannot figure how to change the algorithm to required.

The signature generation happens here:

```
signedXml.ComputeSignature();
```

The only override with a parameter expects `KeyedHashAlgorithm`:

`public void ComputeSignature(KeyedHashAlgorithm macAlg);` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa331491(v=vs.71).aspx))

`KeyedHashAlgorithm` ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5zz2x4d(v=vs.110).aspx)) in turn only allows creating HMAC* and MAC* algorithms and has no RSA-SHA1.

What is the most painless way of signing an XML with RSA-SHA1 in .Net?

**Edit:**

I'm trying to use a X509 certificate to extract the key. Certificate's signature algorithm property is `sha1RSA`.

This is how I'm assigning it:

```
var signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
...
signedXml.SigningKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
...
signedXml.ComputeSignature();
```

The resulting signature xml format matches expected one, however `digest` and `signature` values are invalid.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In .NET Framework 1.1 through .NET Framework 4.7 you get RSA-SHA-1 by simply setting `signedXml.SigningKey` to an RSA key object.

If .NET 4.7.1 (currently in preview) is installed the default for RSA will change to RSA-SHA-2-256, per https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md.

So, if you really want a RSA-SHA-1 signature you need to

a) set `signedXml.SigningKey` to an RSA key

b) set `signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA1Url`

(both before calling `signedXml.ComputeSignature()`)

Conversely, if you want to do something better than RSA-SHA-1 on current versions, set signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod to `SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA256Url` or better.

---

Word of warning: SHA-1 is considered broken for cryptographic purposes now that a collision has been found.  While it's not generalized enough (at this point) to attack arbitrary XML, it may well grow up to that point.  You really shouldn't be using SHA-1 in anything new, and should consider validating that your signature method is something better than SHA-1 based when deciding whether to accept a signed document.

Comment: @user5226582 Ah, SignedXml.SignatureMethod is a readonly projection of the writable SignedXml.SignatureInfo.SignatureMethod.  Fixed the answer.

Comment: @bartonjs, should not it has a third 'c' item for `reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url`? Or isn't that step really necessary for all types of SHA-1 XML signing?

Comment: @PedroGaspar If you want all-SHA-1, then yes.  But the digest for the references and the digest used in the signature don't need to match.